# Logic for Nine to one equals 100

Tags: java

I was recently asked this question in an interview . Can anyone help me with a code to solve this problem?

We have a sequence of non-zero digits 123456789. The problem is to place plus or minus signs between them so that the result of thus described arithmetic operation will be 100. We can use a number only once . However we can use the operators(+,-,*,/) any number of times

Edit : I was asked to write a Java code for this question . So i believe its relevant

The followup question was to get all possible combinations

Comment: This is off-topic for SO but a great topic for http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Interesting question, whatever that is off-topic.

Comment: I was asked to write a Java code for this question . So i believe this question is in topic

Comment: You did not ask for Java code, you asked for instruction on algebra which I assume you know how to turn into Java code.

Comment: Can you group numbers together (ie. 89 as a single value)?

Comment: yes . we can group 89 together . However we cannot use 8 and 9 again

Comment: also consider using http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: no need to perform all combinations you can cache operations done to reduce operations number

Comment: How do we split the numbers and add operators ? . I am looking for an algorithm to solve this problem .

Answer (score 1):

### Example

Here is an example.

Split the numbers as follows

- 1 with multiply
- 4,7,89 with sum
- 3,6 with sum
- 4,5 with subtract

3+6 - 4 - 5 = 0

4 + 7 + 89 = 100

1 * 100 = 100

### Automatic way of finding all possible combinations.

You essentially have 1 set:

- the set {1..9} merged with the set {-,+,/,*,nothing} (nothing being the absence of a symbol)

You need to iterate over all the order possibilities. That will take for a long time. Exclude cases where there are 2 symbols side by side e.g. -/.

I believe this will lead to [k-combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations).

Comment: How do we split these numbers . I mean , do we have any algorithm to split the numbers and add operators ?

Comment: pretty sure the question is for a general collection of numbers, not just the set {1..9}.  Your solution won't work unless the numbers provided are exactly 1..9 with no duplicates and no number missing.

Comment: The  interviewer was very specific with numbers 1-9 . No duplicates . I was asked to write a java code to generate one pattern . the follow up question was to generate all such patterns . I believe there are 11 such patterns (as told by interviewer)